# How can I lifelog with Emacs?

Tags: logging

Is there a package to log Emacs activity?

I've been logging my productive activity with various tools, including shell and browser history.  More I use Emacs, it's hard to track what I do. Because more and more staff is done in Emacs without touching any other tools.

I'm aware of [`command-log-mode`](https://github.com/lewang/command-log-mode).  The latest version has [time-stamps and save capability](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12935/) but it does not log what file I am working on.  Maybe it is a good candidate for a starting point.

I'm also aware that you can time with [`org-mode`](http://orgmode.org/manual/Clocking-work-time.html#Clocking-work-time).  I'm using it but I always forget to switch to new work when I interrupted by my colleagues.

BTW, I'm not interested in *real* life logging with Emacs.  I'm not looking for any extra gadget nor ways to *wear* Emacs.  It sounds interesting but not for now.

Comment: What about Memento? 
  [1]: https://github.com/ehartc/memento

Comment: The org mode clocking is good enough for me. In addition to normal tasks which get DONE at some point, I also have "permanent" entries, like "meetings" "discussions with ...", etc. Since I also forget clocking, I am building a convenience library for adapting clocks fast in https://github.com/dfeich/org-clock-convenience. I am still experimenting and adding functionality.

Comment: @ReneFroger I don't think memento logs what I do under Emacs environment.  It just ask you, when you close your Emacs session, to log your self, IIRC.

Comment: @dfeich Nice add-on.  I'll try to use it.  Care to merge with upstream?  Even with this library, it does not automatically log my activity.   But still +1.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @yasushi-shoji I would be completely ok for merging upstream, eventually, but I need a bit more time to optimize the functionality. There's a number of things I want to change/extend.

Answer (score 4):

`M-x open-dribble-file`

See the Emacs manual, node [Checklist](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Checklist.html) and the Elisp manual, node [Recording Input](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Recording-Input.html).

> Start writing all keyboard characters to a dribble file called FILE.
>   If FILE is nil, close any open dribble file.
>   The file will be closed when Emacs exits.
>
> Be aware that this records ALL characters you type!
>   This may include sensitive information such as passwords.

Answer (score -2):

Does WakaTime meet your need? https://wakatime.com/

From their website:

> Get real-time metrics per project, file, branch, commit, feature, operating system, editor/IDE, language, etc.

Comment: An online service is ok if it does what I need.  WakaTime doesn't seem to handle all of my Emacs activity but only programming, no?